# onbuttonclick - Unity with Bolt

Tags: unity-game-engine, bolt

I am using Unity with Bolt visual scripting and having some issues. I have a 2d Mobile App and basically what I want to do is when the user touches a sprite it starts spinning on every axis. Although I am able to achieve it without the user touching the sprite from the update function.

I want to achieve this through the touch in mobile. How can I do this? There is no on-button click.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved this by making a button and changing its image from the source image to a particular shape .png and then I was able to perform on Click Function.